# highcharts heatmap with getjson

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I need help with this heatmap chart

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var grf_heatmap = {

        chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        renderTo:'map',
        height: 600,
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 40
    },


    title: {
        text: 'heatmap'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: []

    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: []


    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
       maxColor: '#990041'
    },

    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 320
    },


    series: [{

        turboThreshold:0,
        borderWidth: 1,
        point: {

    events: {
      click: function(e) {
        //this.slice();
        //console.log(e);
        location.href = e.point.options.url;
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  },

data:[],

              dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'black',
            style: {
                textShadow: 'none',
                HcTextStroke: null
            }
        }
    }]}
$.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

              grf_heatmap.yAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
              grf_heatmap.xAxis.categories = json[2]['data'];
              grf_heatmap.series[0].data = json[1]['data'];
              chart = new Highcharts.Chart(grf_heatmap);
        });
})
```

data.php retuns a json like this

```
 [{"name":"EjeY",
    "data":["NameA"]},
    {"name":"datos",
    "data":["{x:0,y:0,value:1,url:'test.php'}",
    "{x:1,y:0,value:3,url:'test.php'}"]},
  {"name":"EjeX",
"data":["1","2"]}
]
```

but the result is a blank chart.

what am i doing wrong?,
if i use only the json for xAxis and yAxis categories and complete the chart with this data

```
data[{x:0,y:0,value:1,url:'test.php'},{x:1,y:0,value:3,url:'test.php'}],
```

it works

Tanks,

Comment: This: `"{x:0,y:0,value:1,url:'test.php'}"` is string. You need an object: `{x:0,y:0,value:1,url:'test.php'}` (without quotes).

Comment: But json[1]['data'] is an object  (verified with "type of")

Comment: I'm not convinced.. I certainly see string in your data. Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: ok json[1]['data'][0] and json[1]['data'][1] are strings, how convert it to an object?

Comment: The same way as you created one level higher object. `{"name":"datos",
    "data":["{x:0,y:0,value:1,url:'test.php'}"` - this it's proper object with two properties, `name` and `data`. Your php (I guess) should return proper JSON.